# How to get element from another HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk

I'm very new to tizen web. I have an app that gets data from mqtt broker and controls wi-fi lamp. I have list page with 3 pages, that allow to control brightness, speed, scale. I get data from mqtt every time when the lamp changes its state and I want to update the level in each page.

**index.html**

```
<div class="ui-content">
    <ul class="ui-listview">
        <li class="li-has-toggle">
            <label>
                On/Off
                <div class="ui-toggleswitch" id="toggle">
                    <input class="ui-switch-input" id="t_swtch" type="checkbox" onclick="ToggleSwitch();" />
                    <div class="ui-switch-button"></div>
                </div>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="brightness.html">Brightness</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="speed.html">Speed</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="scale.html">Scalse</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**brightness.html**

```
<body>
    <div class="ui-page" id="dimmer-page">
        <div class="ui-content dimmer-content">
            <div class="ui-dimmer" id="dimmer" data-dimmer-type="BRI"></div>
            <input id="slider" data-slider-type="bri" type="range" value="50" min="0" max="100">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I tried to get element from **brightness.html** like this `document.querySelector("input[data-slider-type='bri']")` to set value, but it returns `null`. When I try to get access to this element of **index.html** `document.getElementById("t_swtch")` and it works fine.
I need to get access to this element from my  **index.html** page.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's the case, but maybe there's a typo in your query. I've tried the exact same query you use, but with the closing `)` -   `document.querySelector("input[data-slider-type='bri']")` and it returned the corresponding  element

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. It works when I'm on **brightness.html**, but I need to get this element when I'm on **index.html**